# How to run Robotium test cases using spoon

Tags: robotium, spoon

I have downloaded Spoon Runner and Spoon Client jar files
I have created .apk file of the test project.
I tried to Run the test using below commands.

```
java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar --apk kk-contacts-kitkat-contacts.apk --test-apk ContactsApplicationTest.apk
```

`ContactsApplicationTest.apk` is the apk i have created of my test project

```
after executing below command it just installed application on connected
```

devices and shows below message.

```
D:\MobileTesting\ContactsApplicationTest\libs>java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.1-jar-w
ith-dependencies.jar --apk kk-contacts-kitkat-contacts.apk --test-apk ContactsAp
plicationTest.apk
2014-08-27 10:57:33 [SR.runTests] Executing instrumentation suite on 2 device(s)
.
D:\MobileTesting\ContactsApplicationTest\libs>
```

What should be --test-apk in spoon command to run the application ?
    Can any one help me how to integrate spoon with *Robotium* in detail.

Comment: There is really few people who is working about that android testing issue with robotium,robolectric and spoon contents. I have same problems,but no good guide on internet... that is distressing...

Answer (score 0):

Integrating spoon with Robotium

Build test project from command prompt by running

```
gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest
```

now the test apk is generated.

**Spoon**

--apk provide full path to the apk you want to test(app-debug.apk) or if you want to test different apk provide the apk path(make sure that both package names are same else generateed test apk does not know which apk to test) and --test-apk is the test apk which is generated after assembleDebugAndroidTest command under ..\outputs\apk\androidTest-unaligned.apk .

**Run the command**

```
java -jar C:\Users\Shivam\Downloads\spoon-runner-1.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar --apk \path\to\your\apk\MyAppApk.apk 
 --test-apk C:\Users\Shivam\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk --sdk E:\sdk
```

Check the index.html in spoon-output folder for test results.